# Canvas drawBitmap not displays bitmap

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I have a custom view and inside `onDraw()` I'm trying to draw specific bitmap which is created from drawable resource.
I'm calling `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,null, dstRect, null)` which must draw this bitmap into the specified `dstRect` region but it doesn't display anything. If I call `canvas.drawRect(dstRect,paint)` it draws rectangle with no problem and it is how it looks like

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE)
    canvas.drawRect(dstRect,paint)
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, dstRect, null)
}
```

[image]

I have also checked and bitmap is created correctly. Source bitmap is 385x389 PNG image 60 KB

If I remove `canvas.drawRect(dstRect,paint)` than only blue screen is showing

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    mResources,
                    R.drawable.your_bitmap
               );

// Initialize a new Bitmap to hold the source bitmap
Bitmap dstBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    dstRect.getRight() - dstRect.getLeft, // Width
                    dstRect.getBottom() - dstRect.getTop(), // Height
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 // Config
            );

// Initialize a new Canvas instance
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(dstBitmap);
canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);

canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, // Bitmap
                   0, // Left offset
                   0, // Top offset
                   null // Paint);
```

Comment: This is not helpful for me, cause I need the bitmap to be scaled with dstRect region

Comment: @JemoMgebrishvili try my updated answer. I have passed your dstRect height width to the canvas and will draw your bitmap to dstRect

Comment: But if it is new canvas object how it will draw anything? to draw something there should be an original canvas as I know.